# Calculating electric field in a dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

Why the electric field calculated in a dielectric is equal to the uniform charge density per unit area divided by epsilon-0 (which is the permitivity in space) shouldn't it be divided by another constant?

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking. What other constant? Please provide more detail about the situation you are asking about and the difficulty you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It should be divided by the relative permittivity.